# Underwater talking

Tags: genetic-engineering, terraforming

In my sci-fi project, Ganymede has been terraformed but a lack of continents meant settlers had to build an artificial island. Over time, however, this island has begun to sink due to weight of the city on it. Unable to build another island, the inhabitants genetically engineer the next generation into aquatic humanoids who inhabit the sunken city. The problem is, even if they can breathe underwater I’m pretty sure they still need air to talk, and it’s really inconvenient to have to swim up to the surface every few minutes when your having a conversation.

So, is it possible to vocalise underwater, by forcing water through a set of vocal chords like air?  Not for humans, I mean, but for some other species?

Comment: Yes, [fish make various sounds](https://fishsounds.net/index.js). Have you tried to do a minimum of research?

Comment: yes, but sounds are produced using an air-filled swim bladder. I could potentially use this by modifying their lungs into a pair of swim bladders and having them respire through gills, and in fact this is probably a better method than what I proposed. Thank you!

Comment: Fun detail of evolutionary history: lungs and swim bladders are [homologous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homology_(biology)). (And many fishes are [physioclistous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physoclisti) -- the gas in their swim bladders is produced and controlled by special organs and does not come from the exterior; it is *not* air.)

Comment: Greetings: please don't put your prior research / ideas down here in comments! Those really belong in a section of your question!

Comment: It seems like there is also the possibility of there being a technology basis, so perhaps some type of transducer rather than being completely organic. The mode of communication can also change from just being speech to something more like clicks and whistles. Marine mammals of course make a lot of sophisticated sounds, but are still using air and a larynx, where as fish and crustacean sounds are more clicks and hums and grunt like sounds.

Answer (score 3):

They could use a non-vocal way to communicate- Think sign language, morse code, or telepathy if needed. If this is a sci-fi world, they could possibly have a device implanted in their brains that allows telepathy within so many feet. Or the more classical approach of sign language could work as well, but perhaps modified to be more accessible.

Comment: Upvote for the possibility of underwater interpretive dance!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a frame challenge for other writers who want to write stories on a terraformed Ganymede.  The story idea by user98816 sounds rather interesting, however improbable i tmay be that the colonists don't simply attache many air filled chambers under their artificial island to keep it floating.

But I suspect that many other stories set on a a terraformed Ganymede would have rather routine plots.

There were many early science fiction stories which depicted Ganymede and other large moons of the giant planets as being naturally habitable for humans.  And other stories depicted them as being capable of being capable of being terraformed to become habitable for for humans, like Heinlein's *Farmer in the Sky* (1950).

But that assumes that the large moons in the outer solar system are made of rock, like the Earth, the Moon, Mars, etc.  Actually the densities of the outer solar system objects can be calculated from their volumes and masses.  Those densities are low enough to make it clear they are made out of rock mixed to varying degrees with significant percentages of ices of water and other compounds.

So the larger moons in the outer solar system have inner rocky spherical cores, with many kilometers and miles of ice on top of the rocky cores.  The outer ice layers are often so thick that their bottom layers have sufficient pressure to melt the bottom layers of ice into water.  Thus some small worlds in the outer solar system are believed to have outer layers of ice floating of top of global oceans on top of their rocky cores.

Accordign to this list:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_largest_lakes_and_seas_in_the_Solar_System

Six bodies in the outer solar system are known to have subsurface global oceans, and another 11 moons and dwarf planets are believed to possibly have subsurface oceans.

Ganymede, the mosst massive moon in the solar system, is naturally one beleived to have a subsurface ocean.

> In the 1970s, NASA scientists first suspected that Ganymede has a thick ocean between two layers of ice, one on the surface and one beneath a liquid ocean and atop the rocky mantle.[8][19][67][70][71] In the 1990s, NASA's Galileo mission flew by Ganymede, and found indications of such a subsurface ocean.[43] An analysis published in 2014, taking into account the realistic thermodynamics for water and effects of salt, suggests that Ganymede might have a stack of several ocean layers separated by different phases of ice, with the lowest liquid layer adjacent to the rocky mantle.[19][20][21][72] Water–rock contact may be an important factor in the origin of life.[19] The analysis also notes that the extreme depths involved (~800 km to the rocky "seafloor") mean that temperatures at the bottom of a convective (adiabatic) ocean can be up to 40 K higher than those at the ice–water interface.>

> In March 2015, scientists reported that measurements with the Hubble Space Telescope of how the aurorae moved confirmed that Ganymede has a subsurface ocean.[43] A large salt-water ocean affects Ganymede's magnetic field, and consequently, its aurora.[18][72][73][74] The evidence suggests that Ganymede's oceans might be the largest in the entire Solar System.[75]
>
> There is some speculation on the potential habitability of Ganymede's ocean.[71][76]

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ganymede_(moon)#Subsurface_oceans

Since there is speculation on the possibility of life in the subsurface oceans in the outer solar system, it would be wrong to terraform a world with a subsurface ocean before finding out whether there is life in the subsurface ocean.

How reasonable would it be to terraform Ganymede?

I note the OP assumes that all of Ganymede has been given a breathable atmosphere at a temperature suitable for humans, thus melting the outer ice shell.

Ganymede has a surface area of 8.72 times 10 to the 7th power square kilometers, or 87,200,000 square kilometers, 0.171 the surface area of Earth.

The continent of Australia, including New Guinea and other islands, has a total land area of 8,600,000 thousand square kilometers, 0.0986 the surface area of Ganymede.  And the colonists would be living on an artificial island smaller in area than Australia.  It seems like wasted effort to terraform the whole moon,
when they could have simply put an airtight roof over their artificial island and kept a breathable atmosphere within the island.

How long can Ganymede retain a breathable atmosphere?

The requirements for a planet to be habitable for humans were discussed by Stephen H. Dole in *Habitable planets for Man* (1964).

https://www.rand.org/content/dam/rand/pubs/commercial_books/2007/RAND_CB179-1.pdf

Dole discussed the ability of a world to retain atmosphere on pages 33 to 38. He wrote on page 34 that there were complex theories about the ablity of worlds to retain atmosphere which require detailed knowlede of the atmopshere.  And there is a rule of thumb for calaculating how long a world can retain 1/*e* of the original amount of gas in its atmosphere - 1/*e* being equal to 0.368 of the origianl  amount. Using that formula Dole calculated how long a world coould retain 0.368 of the original amount of a gas at various ratios of the world's escape velocity divided by the root-mean-square velocity of the gas in the exosphere of the  world's atmosphere.  The hotter the gas, the faster the root-men-square vleocity of the gas particles.  And gases in the exosphere may be several times as hot as on the surface.

Table 5 on page 35 gives how long a world can retain 0.368 of the original amount of a gas at various ratios of the escape veloity divided by the root-mean-square velocity of that gas in the exosphere.

If the ratio is one or two, zero time.

If the ratio is three, a few weeks.

If the ratio is four, a few thousand years.

If the ratio is five, about a hundred million years.

If the ratio is six, infinity.

So a relatively small difference in the ratio can mean a infinite difference in how long the world can retain a gas.  Other factors can accelerate gas loss, and a slow enough gas loss can compensated for by a swift enough production or acquistion of that gas.

On page 54 Dole decided that if - repeat if - the maximum exosphere temperature of world could be as low as 1000 Kelvin, while the surface temperature was warm enough for humans (about 288 Kelvin) the root mean-square velocity of oxygen in the exosphere would be 1.25 kilometers per second, and a world with an escape velocity 5 times that, or 6.25 kilometers per second, could retain oxygen long enough to be considered habitable for humans.

According to Dole onpage 54, a world with an escape velocoty of 6.25 kilometers per second would have mass of 0.195 Earth mass, a radius of 0.63 Earth radius, and a surface gravity of 0.49 *g*.

I have seen another estimate of the lower mass limit for retaining a substantial atmosphere, on pages 3 to 4 of this article:

https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1209/1209.5323.pdf

0.12 Earth mass.  Though other factors suggest 0.25 Earth mass as the appoximate minimum mass for a habitable world.

Kaltenegger, L. 2000, ESA Special Publication, 462, 199.

Williams, D. M., Kasting, J. F., Wade, R. A. 1997, Nature, 385, 234

So how does the mass of GAnymed compared to such minimum masses of 0.12 Earth Mass, 0.195 Earth mass, and 0.25 Earth mass?

The mass of Ganymede is 0.025 Earth mass, from 0.100 to 0.208 the necessary minimum masses.

The escape velocity of Ganymede is 2.741 kilometers per second.  If Ganymede was given a breathable atmosphere and Earth like surface temperatures, its escape velocity would be only 2.1928 the root-mean-square velocity of oxygen in the exosphere of Ganymede (if the maximum temperature in the exosphere is alow as 1000 K).

Since that is much less than the ratio necessary to retain 0.368 of oxygen for a few weeks, we can assume the oxygen level would be down to 0.368 in one week or less, down to 0.135 in two weeks or less, down to 0.049 in three weeks or less, down to 0.0180 in four weeks or less, and so on.

And that is assuming that if the surface of Ganymede is as warm as 288 K the exosphere temperature will be no more than 1000 K.  I don't how much the temperatures in the exosphere of Ganymede would depend on radiation from the Sun, 0.04 as intense as at Earth, and how much on heat rising from the heated surface of Ganymede.

However, new calculations indicate that planets with much lower mass than previusly tought could be habitable.  A water world, which was largely composed of water, could have an atmosphere of water vapor dense enough to moderate the surface temperatures and also to keep the liquid water on the surface from evaporating into outerspace.

Teh calculations indicated the miniummass for such a habitable world would be about 0.0268 the mass of Earth, much less mass than other calculations indicate.  My guess is if such a water world had an Earth like temperature instead of being very cold, the water vapor atmosphere would escape into space quite rapidly, but the planet continously replace that atmosphere from the surface of its world wide ocean for many millions of years.

Unfortunately 0.0268 times the mass of Earth is 1.072 times the mass of Ganymede, 0.025 that of Earth, So Ganymede would probably be unable to retain a water vapor atmosphere for geological eras of time.

https://earthsky.org/space/small-rocky-exoplanets-can-still-be-habitable/

Anyway, the water vapor atmosphere of such a planet would probably have too much water vapor for humans to survive breathing it, even if it also had enough oxygen for humans in its s atmosphere.

But there is one more factor to consider.  Tehe scape velocity of GAnymede is 2.741 kilometers per second, the escape velocoity of Titan is 2.639 kilometers per second, and the escape velocity of Callisto is 2.440 kilometers per second.

But Titan has a thick atmosphere, thicker than that of the Earth, while the "atmospheres" of Ganymede and Callistion a very thin, about a billionth as dense as the atmopshere of Titan.

ON epossible reason why could be that Jupiter, that Ganymede and Callisto orbit, is about 5.2028 times as far from the Sun as Earth, and thus rceives only 1/27.069 (or 0.0369426) as much heat from the Sun as Earth does, while Saturn, that Titan orbits, is about 9.5388 times as far from the Sun as Earth, and thus receives only 1/90.988 (0.0109904) as much heat from the Sun as Earth does.  Which is about 0.2974 as much heat as Ganymede and callisto receive.

Possibly that difference in radiation from the Sun is enough to keep the exosphere of Titan's atmosphere cold enough to retain gases much better than Ganymede and Callisto can.

> The persistence of a dense atmosphere on Titan has been enigmatic as the atmospheres of the structurally similar satellites of Jupiter, Ganymede and Callisto, are negligible. Although the disparity is still poorly understood, data from recent missions have provided basic constraints on the evolution of Titan's atmosphere.
>
> Because Callisto and Ganymede are structurally similar to Titan, it is unclear why their atmospheres are insignificant relative to Titan's. Nevertheless, the origin of Titan's N2 via geologically ancient photolysis of accreted and degassed NH3, as opposed to degassing of N2 from accretionary clathrates, may be the key to a correct inference. Had N2 been released from clathrates, 36Ar and 38Ar that are inert primordial isotopes of the Solar System should also be present in the atmosphere, but neither has been detected in significant quantities.[66] The insignificant concentration of 36Ar and 38Ar also indicates that the ~40 K temperature required to trap them and N2 in clathrates did not exist in the Saturnian sub-nebula. Instead, the temperature may have been higher than 75 K, limiting even the accumulation of NH3 as hydrates.[67] Temperatures would have been even higher in the Jovian sub-nebula due to the greater gravitational potential energy release, mass, and proximity to the Sun, greatly reducing the NH3 inventory accreted by Callisto and Ganymede. The resulting N2 atmospheres may have been too thin to survive the atmospheric erosion effects that Titan has withstood.[67]
>
> An alternative explanation is that cometary impacts release more energy on Callisto and Ganymede than they do at Titan due to the higher gravitational field of Jupiter. That could erode the atmospheres of Callisto and Ganymede, whereas the cometary material would actually build Titan's atmosphere. However, the 2H–1H (i.e. D–H) ratio of Titan's atmosphere is (2.3±0.5)×10−4,[66] nearly 1.5 times lower than that of comets.[65] The difference suggests that cometary material is unlikely to be the major contributor to Titan's atmosphere.[6][68] Titan's atmosphere also contains over a thousand times more methane than carbon monoxide which supports the idea that cometary material is not a likely contributor since comets are composed of more carbon monoxide than methane.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atmosphere_of_Titan#Atmospheric_evolution

Though the diffrence between the atmosphere of Ganymede and CaAllisto on hand and Titan on the other hand is not very well understood, it shouldn't give much hope that Ganymede could retain an atmopshere breathable for humans if it had surfaceand exosphere temperature as high as Earth's.

So terraforming Ganymede to give it a breathable atmosphere with a surface temperature similar to that of Earth seems like bailing out a boat using a sieve.  Ganymede would probablylosing oxygen as fast as it was produced, and the availabe sources of oxygen would relatively soon run out.

Any writer who wants to write a story where Ganymede (or any other moon or dwarf planet with an even lower escape velocity is terraformed to have breathable atmosphere and Earth like temperatures should literally put a lid on the situation, putting some sort of roof to hold the atmosphere in, making that world some sort of shellworld.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shellworld